# How does a game like Doodlejump generate its "level"?

Tags: level-design, procedural-generation

How does the game Doodlejump for iphone generate its stage? Are the platforms randomized in some way? If so, how do they make sure it doesn't generate impossible combinations?

If it's not randomized, how do they make sure it's different (or varied enough) every time?

Comment: Please notice that randomized levels are in most occasions clearly inferior to well-designed levels. Just compare **Abduction** to **Abduction 2** and you'll notice the HUGE gap.

Answer (score 2):

Well, its generated on the fly, and definitely random.

To make sure there is imposible jumps you need to tune your game to generate only possible yet interesting situations. It a really hard topic because it is totally different for each game. Luckily you can learn about some games by looking at it and analyzing how you would generate interesting levels.

One very very very good resource here is an article about [Tuning Canabalt](http://blog.semisecretsoftware.com/tuning-canabalt) on how the developer decided to make it not only possible but also hard, and interesting.

Comment: I guess Doodlejump has it easier than Canabalt as the maximum jump height never changes, it only needs to give the player some platform within that jump range and it's fine. Thanks for the link, interesting stuff.